Lerna published packages contain TypeScript source files instead of built JavaScript file
I'm facing an issue with Lerna and GitHub Actions where the published packages contain TypeScript source files (*.ts) from the src directory instead of the compiled JavaScript files from the dist directory.
In my Lerna configuration (lerna.json):
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/",
      "conventionalCommits": true
    },
    "version": {
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "message": "chore(release): publish"
    }
  },
  "packages": ["src/modules/*"]
}

My scripts:
 {
   "name": "@example/pack",
   "author": "example",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "./dist/index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
     "patch:version": "yarn version --patch --no-git-tag-version",
     "copy:dependencies": "cp package.json dist/package.json && cd dist",
     "npm:publish": "npm run build &&npm run patch:version && npm run copy:dependencies && npm publish"
   },
   "dependencies": {
 ...
   },
   "devDependencies": {
  ...
   },
   "workspaces": [
     "src/modules/module1",
     "src/modules/module2",
     "src/modules/module3",
     "src/modules/module14"
   ],
   "keywords": [],
   "license": "ISC"
 }

Workflow:
name: Automated Build and Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Packages
        run: npx lerna run build

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          npm run copy:dependencies
          npx lerna publish --no-git-tag-version --no-push --y

+----------------------+
| (directory structure) |
+----------------------+
|    dist/
|    node_modules/
|    STC/
|        helpers/
|        modules/
|        shared/
|    .gitignore
|    .npmignore
|    .prettierrc
|    lerna.json
|    package.json
|    tsconfig.json
|    yarn.lock
+----------------------+

Despite these configurations, after installing the packages in node test project, I find in the node_modules/package_folder the TypeScript files instead of the expected compiled JavaScript files.
How to ensure that the published packages contain the built JavaScript files from the dist directory instead of the TypeScript source files?

For one thing you can use a .npmignore file to ignore the src dir

@JaredSmith I have already ignored the src directory in my .npmignore file. I've updated my question to include the directory structure for better clarity.

the .npmignore does not always work, in some cases it could be overriden by other form of ignore/exclude, for example that is the case when you use "files": ["/dist"] in your package.json (which is what I recommend to use in your use case), that will only publish the dist/ folder and the special files in the root like package.json, readme, etc... oh and the files should be added to every package.json of each package

@ghiscoding, I tried adding 'files': ['/dist'] to each package.json, but the published packages only contain empty folders with package.json. After debugging, I found that the dist folder is missing when Lerna runs publish. Even though the build step runs before publishing in GitHub Actions, I seem to be missing a step. Any suggestions?

.npmignore and files can sometime cancel each other out, you have to be careful with them. I would suggest you try with only "files": ["/dist"] and remove all your .npmignore. I also assume you're using Lerna but you could take a look at trying it with Lerna-Lite which also has a --dry-run mode which will package them all but won't push anything to git or npm (it's good for testing). Another thing you could try is to add an npm script "pack-tarball": "npm pack" in one of the package and see what is being packed in the tarball
